# How to open the next view click on the UIImageview?

Tags: iphone, ios

What is the code for imageview when click on the UIImageView then it has to open next view in iPhone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Method 1:

You can put `UIButton` where your `UIImageView` is situated. Set that `UIButton` to custom type and on touchupinside set your `IBAction`.

> Method 2:

What you can do is set background image on `UIButton`, make it of type **Custom** and set `IBAction` on `touchupinside`. This way you do not have to place `UIImageView` in nib. Please have a look at the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 if ([touch view] == image) {

    // image touches
    // write code here for go to another view 
}
else if ([touch view] == image1) {

    // image1 touches
    // write code here for go to another view 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the userinteraction properly of the view to true.
Then use the following touch event to find the touch and push the next view.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == your_ImageViewName)
    {
           write your code here to push the view..   
    }
}
```